# 'undefined is not a function' error at runtime with Angular 2/Typescript function

Tags: angular, typescript, d3.js

I am building an angular (angular2/angular4 not angularJS) component which creates a D3.js Navigation bar.  I have not had any issues with other D3 charts, and it renders just fine initially, but I get a runtime error when trying to access one of the class variables when a "brush" is executed.  (side note: see this for an example of general Javascript D3 brush implementation: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172 )

The error appears to be related to Angular/Typescript and not D3 though:
'undefined is not a function' when trying to access "this.x" in the "brushed()" function in the code below (near the bottom).

Can anyone explain what I need to do to be able to access "this.x" and "this.x.invert" in the "brushed()" function

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, ViewChild, ElementRef, Input, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';
import {StockData} from "../../dataServices/stockData";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navchart',
  templateUrl: './navchart.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navchart.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class NavchartComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @ViewChild('chart') public chartContainer: ElementRef;
  @Input() public stockdata: StockData;

  public margin: any = { top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20, right: 20};
  public width : number;
  public height: number;
  public svg: any;
  public g: any;
  public chart: any;
  public x: any;
  public y: any;
  public navline: any;
  public navarea: any;
  public data: any;
  public brush: any;


  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("Inside the charting - updating the data");
    if (this.stockdata) {
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(this.stockdata));

      this.data = this.stockdata.stocklist;

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.initChart();
        this.drawAxis();
        this.drawRange();
      }, 500);
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges() {

  }

  public initChart(): void {
    let element = this.chartContainer.nativeElement;
    this.width = element.offsetWidth - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.height = element.offsetHeight - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

    this.svg = d3.select(element).append('svg')
      .attr('width', element.offsetWidth)
      .attr('height', element.offsetHeight);

    this.g = this.svg.append('g')
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top +")");


    // x and y scale functions - called every time a value needs converted to pixel location
    //this will need moved to a "redraw" function when adjustments to overall chart size are allowed
    this.x = d3.scaleTime()
            .range([0, this.width]);

    this.x.domain(d3.extent(this.data, (d: any) => new Date(d.date )));

    this.y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .range([this.height, 0]);


      //sets the limits of x and y data.
      // this will need to be moved to a redraw when changes to dataset ranges are allowed
      this.y.domain([
        d3.min(this.data, (d: any) => d.close),
        d3.max(this.data, (d: any) => d.close)
      ]);
      console.log ("Min = " + d3.min(this.data, (d: any) => d.close) );

      // line drawing functions
      this.navline = d3.line()
        .curve(d3.curveBasis)
        .x( (d: any) => this.x(new Date(d.date)) )
        .y( (d: any) => this.y(d.close) );

      this.navarea = d3.area()
        .curve(d3.curveBasis)
        .x( (d: any) => this.x(new Date(d.date)) )
        .y1( (d: any) => this.y(d.close) )
        .y0( (d: any) => this.height );



      this.g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .call(d3.brushX().on("end",  this.brushed));
  }


 /* Error is in this function.  It cannot find "this.x" from the class,
  * and gives an undefined error.
  *  Right now the function is just setting debug content, but when 
  * this.x is working, I will add .invert() to it to get the original
  * date values associated with the pixel location on the x-axis.
  */
  public brushed(): void {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(d3.event.selection));
    //returns proper [x0,x1] pixel values such as [102,500] on a svg 800 pixels wide.

    let dat: any = d3.event.selection.map( this.x);
    //let dat: any = d3.event.selection.map( this.x.invert) also fails with "invert does not exist on undefined"
    console.log(JSON.stringify(dat));

    //The error appears to be because it can't find this.x, even though that is declared and works in
    // other sections of the same class.
  }

  //draw x and y axes
  public drawAxis(): void {
      this.g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(this.x));

    }

    public drawRange(): void {

      this.g.append("path")
        .attr("class", "area")
        .attr("d",  this.navarea(this.data) );


      this.g.append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d",  this.navline(this.data) );
    }


}
```

If it is important, the data is simply an array of daily stock entries in the format:

[ {date, open, high, low, close} ...]
{"date":"2017-06-07 13:02:00","open":"72.6350","high":"72.7700","low":"71.9500","close":"72.0800","volume":"9247460","adjClose":"72.6350"}

D3 likes to use the "d" reference

Comment: Have you tried adding typings? i.e. `npm install --save @types/d3`

Comment: Yes.  I have the D3.js types installed.  The full 'd3' set is available in typings.d.ts.  Just to be clear - the chart actually renders just fine.  It is not until I try to execute a "brush" that it hits the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note*, this question is really a duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38945311/typescript-d3-v4-context-of-this-in-d3-drag-onend-this-dragended).  I'd usually close it as such but that question doesn't explain what's going on, so I'll take a shot here.

---

You are passing a callback function to `.call`.  In that callback `d3` has changed what the variable `this` is referencing.  It is no longer referencing your class but rather the `g` node from the selection.

So you have two choices.  One, wrap it in an ES6 fat arrow function:

```
.call( d3.brushX().on("end", () => this.brushed() ) );
```

This creates a closure around `this` and preserves the reference to your class.

Or, two, use `.bind` to preserve this.  `.bind` forces the preservation of this.

```
.call( d3.brushX().on("end", this.brushed.bind(this) ) );
```

Here's some [excellent reading](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript) on this subject.